# Looping through a generator that returns multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x

My generator (`batch_generator`) returns 5 values, but I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the values.

Things I've tried:

1) Unpack directly in the for loop definition (`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)`)

```
for a, b, c, d, e in next(batch_generator):
    # do something with a-e
```

2) Unpack within the for loop (`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)` on the line where I unpack `item`)

```
for item in next(batch_generator):
    a, b, c, d, e = item
    # do stuff
```

3) Zip it and unpack in the for loop definition (`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)`)

```
for a, b, c, d, e in zip(next(batch_generator)):
    # do stuff
```

4) Zip it and unpack within the for loop (`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 1)` on the line where I unpack `item`, I think it's just wrapped in another tuple now)

```
for item in zip(next(batch_generator)):
     a, b, c, d, e = item
```

Any explanation of what's really going on with the tuples/generator would be appreciated!

Comment: But it emits 5 items, it does not emit tuples of five elements?

Comment: can you show what exactly batch generator is returning

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- is there a difference? My yield statement looks like `yield a, b, c, d, e`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My yield statement looks like `yield a, b, c, d, e`

Based on that comment, the generator seems to emit a sequence of 5-tuples.

You can then simply use:

```
for a, b, c, d, e in batch_generator:
    #                ^ no next(..)
    pass
```

So you should **not use `next(..)`. Next simply returns the next `yield`**. Now since that is a tuple, the `for` loop will **iterate over the tuple**, instead of the generator.

The `for` loop will iterate over the tuples the generator `batch_generator` emits, until the generator is exhausted (or there is a `break`/`return` statement in the `for` loop that is activated.

Mind that a `for` loop works like:

```
for <pattern> in <expression>:
    # ...
```

The `<expression>` should be an iterable (generator, tuple, list,...) and the `<pattern>` is used to assign to. If you iterate over the tuple, you thus iterate over the *elements* of that tuple, not the tuple in full.

Comment: Ah, what a simple fix I overlooked -- thanks so much for the clear explanation!