# How to loop over a generator that returns multiple output?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and I have a following question regarding a generator. My generator yields three variables:

```
def generate():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        j = i + 1
        k = i ** 2
        yield i, j, k
```

In the following function, I would like to loop over the variable `j` only. Of course, this works:

```
for var_i, var_j, var_k in generate():
    print("This is my varible j: ", var_j)
```

But I have two unused variables here - `var_i, var_k`. So I would like to ask, if there is a better way, how to do this?

This answer did not help me: [Looping through a generator that returns multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553925/looping-through-a-generator-that-returns-multiple-values)
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not really, just ignore the unused variables. You could make another generator which only yields the second value, but that just makes it more complicated… `for j in (i[1] for i in generate()): ...`.

Comment: You can put an underscore `_` in place of the 2 unused variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The convention is to use `_` as a variable when you're not interested in using the value.

```
for _, var_j, _ in generate():
```